# Disable Flags From Being Used in Bash Script Input?

Tags: linux, bash, security, input, grep

I am currently making a Bash Script to take the users' input and pass it through [Grep](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/).
I don't have much, but the requirements for this script do not require for much either. One requirement for the script is to create the script securely (via secure scripting).

The problem I am running into is that flags can be passed into Grep which lead to things an average user does not want. Running `--help` in my input brings up the same as `grep --help`, for example. Here is what I have so far:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Input string: " input
[ -z "$input" ] || grep "$input" ../dict.txt
```

One thing to note is that I am trying to keep my code as minimal as possible while keeping it secure (where keeping it secure is the main priority).

Comment: A lot of commands accept `--` as the end-of-options, so you can do `grep -- "$input"`

Comment: @Fravadona What about flags with one letter after? `-i` is an example. Also is someone's input is `help`, it will produce the same as `grep --help`.

Comment: @Fravadona Sorry I miswrote the code and had no space between the last dash and quote. I think this blocks out everything else too? I'm not totally sure, but from the way the two dashes act (where it gave a flag of nothing), I don't think the user could get unexpected or different results than from what they want. Thanks! I'll put the answer, give you the credit, but will not accept as other people may chime in and find a better solution or a potential problem with the existing.

Comment: `grep -- --help file.txt` will search for `--help` inside file.txt

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix can be done here:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Input string: " input
[ -z "$input" ] || grep -- "$input" ../dict.txt
```

The double dash here acts as a flag without a value here which is useful for anyone trying to use the script for intended uses only. I give all credit to @[Fravadona](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3387716/fravadona).